# show progressdialog not showing in asyctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

During android app onCreate I have a bunch of code that can be slow on some older devices.  I want to have a progressdialog display while all the init code runs.  Dialog won't show if called from onCreate because further code blocks the UI.  So it needs to go into an AsyncTask.

This is my task.

```
class startupTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(mainContext);
        pd.setMessage("Starting up.  Please wait...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pd.show();
                runInit();
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (pd != null) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

But the dialog still does not show?  runInit is the usual slow startup code.  It needs to run on the UI.

If I remove the pd.dismiss call the progress dialog does appear once the init codeis finished, so it is being created OK, just not displaying.

According to other posts the above code is the right way to do it, but when called from onCreate it does not seem to work?

Any ways to force a dialog to display after a call to show?  Any way I can get the dialog to show and wait until it is visible before continuing?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: In the end I just had to bite the bullet and reorganise code so that only the slow non UI code was inside the AsyncTask.  This got it working.

Comment: Why are you calling `pd.show();`  in `doInBackground`?

Comment: Just an attempt to get the dialog showing.  It didn't help.

Comment: Your problem is in the statement "runInit is the usual slow startup code. It needs to run on the UI".  This defeats the purpose of the asynctask which is to move that stuff out of the UI thread.  Describe what runInit() is doing and someone can help you find a way to do it outside the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

What's your runInit is doing? You're running on the UI thread, it's being blocked the same way.

Comment: Yes, runInit is (and needs to be) running on the UI thread.  Is there any other way I can get a progressdialog to show before running the UI threead code?

Comment: The progress is being showed but blocked right after, I shouldn't r be running this on the UI or you're not following best practices. To help we need  info of what the runInit is doing.

Answer (score 0):

onPreExecute(), onPostExecute() and onProgressUpdate() have access to the UI Thread, but doInBackground() doesn't.

if runInit() does something on the UI it's being blocked and may be generating an exception that you're ignoring.

you should do operations on doInBackground and use publishProgress() to send to onProgressUpdate() data that you want to update to your UI / ProgressBar Status.

here's an example:

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Object,Void>()
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        Object[] _progress = new Object[]{"Decompressing", 1};
        publishProgress(_progress);               
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params)
    {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values)
    {
        txtProgress.setText(values[0].toString());
        progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[1].toString()));
    }
}.execute();
```